# Why List<String> is not acceptable as List<Object>?

Tags: java, generics, casting

Consider below method `doSomething(List<Object>)` which accepts `List<Object>` as parameter.

```
private void doSomething(List<Object> list) {
    // do something
}
```

Now consider below code snippet which tries to call `doSomething()` where I try to pass `List<String>` to `doSomething()`

```
List<Object> objectList;
List<String> stringList;

doSomething(stringList); // compilation error incompatible types
doSomething(objectList); // works fine
```

Even below code throws compilation error

```
objectList = stringList;  // compilation error incompatible types
```

My question is why `List<String>` can not be passed to a method which accepts `List<Object>`?

Comment: Check out this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html

Comment: `List<? extends Object>` should allow that to work

Comment: @AbstractChaos true, as long as "do something" does not involve `List#add(...)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This generic question in Java may look confusing to any one who is not very familiar with Generics as in first glance it looks like String is object so `List<String>` can be used where `List<Object>` is required but this is not true. It will result in compilation error.

It does make sense if you go one step further because `List<Object>` **can store anything** including `String`, `Integer` etc but `List<String>` can only store `Strings`.

Also have a look at: [Why not inherit from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)

Comment: The problem is not exactly that the called can store anything: the real problem is, if it would be allowed, the caller would not be sure of having a String instance, so would have to handle it as in pre-generics days (instanceof operator).

Answer (score 53):

Because while `String` extends `Object`, `List<String>` does not extend `List<Object>`

**Update:**
In general, if `Foo` is a subtype (subclass or subinterface) of `Bar`, and `G` is some generic type declaration, it is not the case that `G<Foo>` is a subtype of `G<Bar>`.

This is because collections do change. In your case, If `List<String>` was a subtype of `List<Object>`, then types other than `String` can be added to it when the list is referenced using its supertype, as follows:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>;
List<Object> objectList = stringList;// this does compile only if List<String> where subtypes of List<Object>
objectList.add(new Object());
String s = stringList.get(0);// attempt to assign an Object to a String :O
```

and the Java compiler has to prevent these cases.

More elaboration on [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html) Java Tutorial page.

Comment: +1; anyway you can call doSomething(((List<Object>)(List<?>) stringList))

Answer (score 17):

You could put an object of a wrong type into the list *IF* this worked:

```
private void doSomething(List<Object> list) {
    list.add(new Integer(123)); // Should be fine, it's an object
}

List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
doSomething(stringList); // If this worked....
String s = stringList.get(0); // ... you'd receive a ClassCastException here
```

Comment: P.S.: The supertype/subtype relationships with generics are explained very well at http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ207

Answer (score 5):

The reason for these limitations have to do with variance considerations.

Take the following code:

```
public void doSomething(List<Object> objects)
{
  objects.add(new Object());
}
```

Expanding your example, you could try to do the following:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
string.add("S1");

doSomething(strings);

for (String s : strings)
{
  System.out.println(s.length);
}
```

Hopefully it's obvious why this would break if the compiler allowed this code to be compiled (which it doesn't) - a `ClassCastException` would occur for the second item in the list when trying to cast the `Object` to a `String`.

To be able to pass generalized collection types, you need to do this:

```
public void doSomething(List<?> objects)
{
  for (Object obj : objects)
  {
    System.out.println(obj.toString);
  }
}
```

Again, the compiler is watching your back and were you to replace the `System.out` with `objects.add(new Object())` the compiler wouldn't allow this because `objects` could have been created as `List<String>`.

For more background on Variance see the Wikipedia artical [Covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 3):

It is sometimes expected that a `List<Object>` would be a supertype of a `List<String>` , because `Object` is a supertype of `String` .

This expectation stems from the fact that such a type relationship exists for arrays:

`Object[]` is a supertype of `String[]` , because `Object` is a supertype of `String` . (This type relationship is known as covariance .)

The super-subtype-relationship of the component types extends into the corresponding array types.

**No such a type relationship exists for instantiations of generic types. (Parameterized types are not covariant.)**

Check [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Topic2) for more details

Answer (score 3):

**From Java Tutorials of Generics:**

Let's test your understanding of generics. Is the following code snippet legal?

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>(); // 1
List<Object> lo = ls; // 2
```

Line 1 is certainly legal. The trickier part of the question is line 2. This boils down to the question: is a List of String a List of Object. Most people instinctively answer, "Sure!"

Well, take a look at the next few lines:

```
lo.add(new Object()); // 3
String s = ls.get(0); // 4: Attempts to assign an Object to a String!
```

Here we've aliased ls and lo. Accessing ls, a list of String, through the alias lo, we can insert arbitrary objects into it. As a result ls does not hold just Strings anymore, and when we try and get something out of it, we get a rude surprise.

**The Java compiler will prevent this from happening of course. Line 2 will cause a compile time error.**

Source : [Generics and Subtyping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure what datatype it will take in you can make use of Generics in Java as follows

```
public static void doSomething(List<?> data) {

}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    doSomething(objectList);
    doSomething(stringList);
}
```

But while using the data, you will be required to specify proper data type as a Type Cast

Comment: No relation to the question, I think

Comment: Ya, I know has no relation to question, but since you had added proper comment at the question, thought it would be good to share possible Generic way using Generics in Java :-/