# Java Method declaration returning List Generics with reference

Tags: java, list, generics

Could you explain why the first one does not work?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyClass {

    private <T extends Object> List<Class<T>> getList1() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private <T extends Object> List<Class<T>> getList2(Class<T> cls) {
        List<Class<T>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(cls);
        return list;
    }

    private List<Class<? extends Object>> getList3() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        // 1. Not OK - The method add(Class<Object>) in the type List<Class<Object>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<String>)
        myClass.getList1().add(String.class);
        // 2. OK
        myClass.getList2(String.class);
        // 3. OK
        myClass.getList3().add(String.class);
    }

}
```

I thought `getList1()` is returning a `List` of classes those extend from `Object`, and `String` is one of those?

And no this is not a duplicated question (at least not to the one being linked). If I really defined a List of Object, of course I don't want it to take a List of String. But here I am accepting a List of Object plus those extending from Object, so the question is why didn't it accept String in the first case.

Comment: Because the compiler cannot infer the type of `T`, so it defaults to `Object`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why List<String> is not acceptable as List<Object>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144671/why-liststring-is-not-acceptable-as-listobject)

Comment: I disagree this is a duplicate as I am asking why `List<T extends Object>` not accepting `List<String>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call the method like this:

```
myClass.<String>getList1().add(String.class);
```

Somehow the compiler needs to know what your `T` should be (the `<String>` is called a [type witness](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)).

---

- Using your method `getList2(String.class)` you specify this by passing in the parameter.
- Using your method `getList3()` the declaration itself uses a wildcard (`?`) so you do not have to specify `T`, but your list will not be strongly typed (it will accept every class extending `Object`).

Comment: Wow, never seen this before. What is this `<String>` coming from? And I thought the compiler can tell from my last `add(String.class)`?

Comment: Have a look here (especially the part about the type witness): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the page you suggested but still am not sure why the first method didn't compile. Especially at the very bottom of the page it said type witness is no longer needed in J8, in which the compile can infer the type from the parameter. So `.add(String.class)` should infer `T` as `String`, and hence the same `T = String` be used in `getList1()`, no?

Comment: I understand what you mean and I have to honestly confess I do not exactly know the answer. Out of personal interest I posted a follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45294380/generic-type-resolution-compiler-steps