# Generic Type Resolution - Compiler Steps

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

Assume the following methods (Java 8):

```
public <T> List<Class<T>> getList() {
  return new ArrayList<>();
}

public <T> List<T> getList2() {
  return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And the following code using those methods:

```
@Test
public void testLists() {
  getList().add(String.class); // Does not compile
  this.<String>getList().add(String.class); // Compiles
  getList2().add(String.class); // Compiles
}
```

The second and third call compile fine, whereas the first one gives:

> `add(java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object>)` in List cannot be applied to
>   `add(java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>)`

---

I do not fully understand the resolution steps here, maybe someone could explain why I need the type witness and the compiler does not infer the type automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the compiler doesn't/cannot infer generic arguments based on future method calls.

In your case, when you call `getList()` or `getList2()` the type `T` is already inferred as `Object`. This means `getList()` will return you an `List<Class<Object>>` object and you cannot add a `Class<String>` object into it.

In your third statement, you have `List<Object>` so you are able to add a `Class<String>` to it.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand, thank you for the simple explanation.

Comment: But this is not some "future" calls on a few lines further down. Its the immediate call chained together with an immediate dot right after.

Comment: @user1589188, Ya, it doesn't work on chained method calls as well for now, but it's part of JEP: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101

Comment: @Codebender I giggled seeing it is the "101" yet it is still not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

In a word, `String` is a `Object`, whereas `Class<String>` is not a `Class<Object>`

ref:[javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html)

Answer (score 0):

use something like this in place of:

```
getList().add(String.class);

<String>getList().add(String.class);
for
 public <T> List<Class<T>> getList() {
  return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Now when you call it, the parameter and return type must match.